# Можно ли провести процесс комплиляции только одного AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: java, android, компиляция

Стоит задача: изменить версию пакета и его доменное имя, изменив эти параметры в AndroidManifest.xml. Поскольку с Java не знаком, могу предположить, что и мой вопрос довольно глупый. В сети нашел только информацию о процессе комплиляции всего Java проекта, что мне не нужно.

Цели, которые я преследую: есть пакет Apk с программой Hello World - кнопка с текстом. Мне нужно открыть Apk пакет, и заменить доменное имя и версию пакета, попутно добавив в пакет код вместо Hello World. То есть пакет Hello World, это своего рода шаблон.

Зачем это нужно? Есть идея сделать генератор Apk Builder прямо на смартфоне. Пользователь указал версию своего проекта, доменное имя, путь к своему проекту, программа берет шаблон Hello World, добавляет файлы проекта пользователя в этот шаблон... Причем ничего компилировать не нужно - проект Hello World написан не на Java. Единственное, что нужно редактировать - AndroidManifest с его последующей компилцией.

Ну, и отсюда вопрос, собственно, можно ли провести процесс комплиляции только одного AndroidManifest.xml с помощью компилятора java, javac или другой консольной утилиты?

Comment: Даже если такое сделаете вам нужно будет еще как-то подписать Apk на устройстве приватным ключем

Comment: Мне уже не нужна декомпиляция, мне нужно  скомпилировать AndroidManifest, который я создам. Подпись APK уже не проблема.